# Decompiling .NET 2.0 binary

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering, decompiling

Is it possible to decompile a .NET 2.0 binary file (*.exe) to some sort of readable code? Or if not, just extract some information from it (for example method names, debugging information, etc.)?

Comment: Bear in mind hat you *might* end up violating the licence agreement by doing this...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to look at [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), it should show you the assembly as C# or IL.

EDIT:

With the increased cost of Reflector, I have switched to [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) for my day to day needs.

Comment: Reflector is the best tool I've ever used for Reversing :))

Comment: Reflector also works well for converting code, say from VB.NET to C#.

Comment: Yeah there is a nice "dissassembly"-plugin that exports complete libraries to cs-files.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the exe into ILDASM or Dot Net Reflector should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Search for Lutz Roeder and you'll find :

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 1):

I will Quote myself from this [question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272581/reverse-engineering-c-programs/2272595#2272595):

> You can never get back to the exact
>   same source since there is no
>   meta-data about that saved with the
>   compiled code.
>
> But you can re-create code out from
>   the assembly-code.
>
> Check out this book if you are
>   interested in these things: Reversing:
>   Secrets of Reverse Engineering.
>
> Edit
>
> Some compilers-101 here, if you were
>   to define a compiler with another word
>   and not as technical as "compiler",
>   what would it be?
>
> Answer: Translator
>
> A compiler translates the syntax /
>   phrases you have written into another
>   language a C compiler translates to
>   Assembly or even Machine-code. C# Code
>   is translated to IL and so forth.
>
> The executable you have is just a
>   translation of your original text /
>   syntax and if you want to "reverse it"
>   hence "translate it back" you will
>   most likely not get the same structure
>   as you had at the start.
>
> A more real life example would be if
>   you Translate from English to German
>   and the from German back to English,
>   the sentance structure will most
>   likely be different, other words might
>   be used but the meaning, the context,
>   will most likely not have changed.
>
> The same goes for a compiler /
>   translator if you go from C to ASM,
>   the logic is the same, it's just a
>   different way of reading it ( and of
>   course its optimized ).

Regarding C#, you have already been given a lot of great tools like Reflector. However, if the Code is obfuscated you are going to have problems reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  First all .net libraries have manifests with type information it them. They can be interrogated problematically using reflection, or by using tools like reflector.  Take a look at the system.reflection namespace for the classes you will need to take a look at.