# How to run debug with c

Tags: c, debugging

Good day, i only have the file which is :
sample_: `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped`

When i run it, it gives an segmentation fault. I tried the debugging with the `gdb`, but the result was : `Reading symbols from sample_...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`

Then i tried with the `file` command :

```
(gdb) file sample_ 
Reading symbols from sample_...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

I dont have the .c file itself.

How i can debug it?

Comment: Compile with `-g` flag on.

Comment: I can not compile, i have just a file itself, no other .c files

Comment: Then it was not compiled with the `-g` flag on, there is little to do :(

Comment: Are there any other methods? I could dump it, but there are lots of assembly codes, which makes it hard to understand

Comment: If you don't have the source code for it you can only inspect the assembly code. Which, without debugging symbols, may turn out to be very hard to read

Comment: You can try with `valgrind`, maybe it gives you some information about the segfault. Anyway, if you can not recompile, why bother?

Comment: wow  @DavidRanieri its 1st time i have ever heard this tool, and it worked. ==10951== Memcheck, a memory error detector. I just need to know as much as possible about this file , thats why i have to do it =)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the program has not been build with debug flags. If you don't have the source to recompile it with debug flags there is as far as I know no way to properly debug it. You can try to [decompile the executable but good luck with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2272595/6796428)